# ThreadPool Vs Task Vs Async

Tags: async-await, task-parallel-library, task, threadpool

I have the following code that shows sending an email. I can achieve this through *ThreadPool, Task and Async*. The caller (in this case Main) is not interested in what comes back.

As I understand, all three methods create an additional thread so the end result is the same.

Please share if you find any other difference, or which should be the right way in .NET 4.5?

*PS. If you want to copy the code and run it, make sure you select the startup object in the project settings. You can select one of the startup Main methods.*

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncTest
{
    class ThreadPoolProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Dont care what SendEmail returns
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SendEmail));
        }

        static void SendEmail(Object stateInfo)
        {
            // Create a SMTP client, send an email and wait for the SMTP client to return!

            // Takes 2 seconds
        }
    }

    class TaskProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Dont care what SendEmail returns
            Task.Run(() => SendEmail());
        }

        static void SendEmail()
        {
            // Create a SMTP client, send an email and wait for the SMTP client to return!

            // Takes 2 seconds
        }
    }

    class AsyncProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Don't await for an answer from the SendMail
            // var r = await SendEmail();

            SendEmail(); // Call without await
        }

        static Task<bool> SendEmail()
        {
            // Create a SMTP client, send an email and wait for the SMTP client to return!

            // Takes 2 seconds

            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad example. The answer here is "none of the above, use SendMailAsync"

Comment: I assume you are suggesting to use SendMailAsync which comes as part of some .NET library. But in this case I don't have any library, but some synchronous code in the SendEmail method which takes 2 seconds to run. You can also assume the SendEmail comes from some legacy code which does not return a task (no async). My question is around the thread, task and async usage in .NET 4.5.

Comment: _"My question is around the thread, task and async"_ - but also about Program.Main() ?  The context matters a lot.

Comment: The Main does not matter. The call can be from a WebAPI method call also. The call in that context is async itself but even that call itself is not interested in the return value from the SendMail.

Comment: Three options are not directly comparable, Initial ThreadPool code is obsolete post .Net 4.0 introduction of TPL, which has Thread Pool redesigned, If you use Task.Run, then you are hiving off the task to a separate thread and Async doesn't have a separate thread it runs in same context, so it has to be the best option, but you do not have a Async Await call out here

Comment: Ideally you should plan to make SendEmail code Async and add an Await when you are waiting to send an Email. That way you would not be taking up system resources, while doing this work, would be an ideal case, vis-a-vis other two

Comment: [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a reasonable question but the context makes it hard to give a good answer.

You are using a Console program and *Dont care what SendEmail returns*. That is not the normal case.

`async`/`await` uses `Task`s that run on top of the ThreadPool. so your 'vs' doesn't hold up. And normally you would at least care about errors that occurred.

When you really don't care about errors or results, `QueueUserWorkItem()` is the most basic approach.

In most contexts however you would aim for an awaitable Task. The SmtpClient.SendAsync() is not awaitable, so a Task that runs the synchronous Send() seems most appropriate.

And when it is really about sending (bulk) mails you would have a few other issues to tackle, like throttling the number of parallel calls.

Comment: I looked at 'SmtpClient.SendAsync' method. If I use that method instead of the legacy sync method I have, I don't have to use any of these methods because 'SmtpClient.SendAsync' creates it's own thread. Am I right?

Comment: Hopefully it wouldn't create a Thread but use I/O completion ports. And yes, for a truly Fire&Forget operation that is the most direct way.

Comment: Does any IO operation like calling ReadAsync (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx) using WebClient or reading a file using ReadLineAsync (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readlineasync(v=vs.110).aspx) use I/O completion ports and don't create a new thread at all?